# Recvfrom and Wireshark

Tags: c, sockets, wireshark, recvfrom

I communicate with a server, i send a message with a socket (sock_raw..), it's works fine, the client (me), send the message, the server receive the right message, but when the server need to send it to me (the client), the client don't retrieve the right information with the recv from.

I retrieve this on two calls server->client :

```
buffer = [E] | len_buffer = [2]
buffer = [E] | len_buffer = [2]
```

But my buffer need to be equal to this data and have this size :

***First call (Data in hexadecimal with 10 bytes)***
[image]

***And Second call (Data in hexadecimal with 2 bytes)***
[image]

This is how i use the recvfrom function (t->sock is the socket fd of the server, t->msg_recv is the buffer created to receive the msg from the servern and t->_recv is the sockaddr* struct for the receive):

```
if (recvfrom(t->sock, t->msg_recv, sizeof(t->msg_recv), 0, \
    (struct sockaddr *)&t->_recv, \
    (socklen_t[1]){sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)}) < 0) {
        perror("recvto()");
        exit(84);
    }
```

Barmar here is the output of the Wireshark message send :

[image]

Here is the code of send and recvfrom on the same function :

```
int len = 0;
    if (sendto(t->sock, t->buffer, t->ip->tot_len, 0,
               (struct sockaddr *)&t->_sin, sizeof(t->_sin)) < 0) {
      perror("sendto()");
      exit(84);
    }
    if ((len = recvfrom(t->sock, t->msg_recv, sizeof(t->msg_recv), 0, \
    (struct sockaddr *)&t->_recv, \
    (socklen_t[1]){sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)})) < 0) {
        perror("recvto()");
        exit(84);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have backslashes at the end of the lines? C doesn't require that except in macros.

Comment: How do you know the client isn't receiving the right information?

Comment: Where do you set `len_buffer`?

Comment: Because the right information is the information in the Wireshark, the hexadecimal message with a length of 10, but i only receive a E with a size of 2 @Barmar

Comment: The len_buffer is set my my.h, the size is set to 256 like `msg_recv[256]` in the t struct.

Comment: The backslashes are useless, just to be more clearer for me..

Comment: What do you mean by "I only receive a E with a size of 2"? `recvfrom()` returns the length of the packet, but you don't assign that anywhere.

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi Can you capture the response of your server in Wireshark, what is actually on the wire that the server is sending?

Comment: Are you trying to print the buffer as a string? It's not a string, it's binary data. `E` is the `45` byte at the end of the first row of the hex, and there's a zero byte after it. Since you're using a raw socket, you get the IP and UDP headers in the buffer.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to print the buffer as a string, but what can i do to have the same resulat like the Wireshark when i print it ? @Barmar

Comment: The two screen wireshark are the response sended by my server at the two calls. @user3469811

Comment: use a loop to print hex bytes.

Comment: And it will solve my problem ? because i already converted the string in hex bytes but it print me the E in hexa... so how can i do this ?? @Barmar

Comment: can you post the codeline that prints out `buffer = [E] | len_buffer = [2]`, and what you expect the output to be on stdout

Comment: I do this just after my recvfrom : `printf("buffer = [%s] | len_buffer = [%d]\n", t->msg_recv, strlen(t->msg_recv));` And for my final stdout, i want to have the blue colored Data like in the wireshark. @user3469811

Comment: `strlen` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`. The correct format specifier is `%zu`, not `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer is not a string, it's binary data, so you shouldn't print it with `%s`.

You need to get the length of the buffer when you call `recvfrom`. Then use a loop that prints each byte with `%02X` format.

```
len = recvfrom(t->sock, t->msg_recv, sizeof(t->msg_recv), 0, \
    (struct sockaddr *)&t->_recv, \
    (socklen_t[1]){sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)});
if (len < 0) {
        perror("recvto()");
        exit(84);
}
for (int i = 0; i < len; i ++) {
    printf("%02X ", t->msg_recv[i]);
    if (i % 16 == 15) {
        printf("\n");
    } else if (i % 16 == 7) {
        printf(" ");
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: `%X` expects an unsigned int, so you may have to use a cast there.

Comment: Is it normal ? my len, so the return of the recvfrom is always equal to 0. Why ? @Barmar

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi A return value of 0 means "end of file"; in the case of sockets, this means the write end on the other side has disconnected. Alternatively it could mean you got the code wrong; check your parentheses.

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi Make sure you added the parentheses correctly around the assignment in the `if` statement. It's a common mistake. If you don't do it correctly, you set `len` to the result of `<`.

Comment: I've split the assignment into a separate statement to make it clearer.

Comment: What is this: `(socklen_t[1]){sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)}`? Is this a new C11 syntax I don't know about?

Comment: @Barmar It's a very new feature: Compound literals. It's only 20 years old (see C99, 6.5.2.5).

Comment: By the way it worked, but this is the message that i have sent and not the message returned by the server, so this is not what i needed.. @Barmar

Comment: @melpomene Thanks. I'm not really a professional C programmer, I just play one on  SO.

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi That makes no sense. `recvfrom` won't return a message you sent, it only returns a message that was received.

Comment: But this is the output that i got and the Wireshark with the first message send : `len = 40 || hex :
45 10 00 28 24 FFFFFFB9 00 00  40 11 57 FFFFFFFA 7F 00 00 01 
7F 00 00 01 1F FFFFFF90 11 FFFFFFC1  00 14 00 00 63 6C 69 65 
6E 74 20 68 65 6C 6C 6F ` and the Wireshark : (i added the img at the end of the subject) @Barmar

Comment: What kind of socket is this? Is it a packet capturing socket? Then it will return both sent and received packets, but they have to match your filtering specification. Maybe your filter only matches the packets you're sending.

Comment: You've left out so much important information from the question.

Comment: Here is the socket : `t->sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);`

Comment: Then I really can't explain why this code on the client is showing the message it sent instead of what it received from the server.

Comment: I send and recvfrom in the same function, i putted the code in the end of my subject @Barmar

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, since my code is only printing `t->msg_recv`, not `t->buffer`.

Comment: True, and i really dont understand why.. :(